# Question about this Korean slang term

Tags: vocabulary, translation

Can someone help?

A friend of mine came across this term.

하나 만들지

His girlfriend from Korea texted it to a friend when she was visiting the US. He thinks it might be very derogatory and even racist. Can some of you please elaborate on the meaning? Is it ever used as a joke or always disparaging? Thanks!

Any and all comments are welcome!

---

The full context of the message was:

- A: 미쿡입니당 낼귀국한다
- B: 좋 네
- A: 일했거 등 ㅋ
- B: 좋네 일 핑계 있어서
- B: 양놈 하나 만들지

Comment: Why does he think that? This question is probably a better fit for chat.https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language

Comment: The sentence itself without context is not offensive in any aspect.

Comment: Your friend looks at his girlfriend's text without permission and thinks it's racist, even though he has no idea what it says? It just says "make one" or "making one" or whatever.  (Without context we can't really say what it means.)

Comment: That is not a slang expression at all.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comments.   I think the full context of the message was:          person 1: 미쿡입니당 낼귀국한다      
person 2   좋 네    
person 1  일했거 등 ㅋ  
person 2    좋네 일 핑계 있어서     
person 2    양놈 하나 만들지

Comment: ['양놈'](https://koreanwordaday.tumblr.com/post/57787466587/the-character-%E6%B4%8B-%EC%96%91-yang-is-of-used-as) relates to why he thinks so. "양놈 하나 만들지" means "Why not get a western boyfriend?" If B is A's boyfriend, it seems to be just a joke suggesting his feeling of inferiority to American guys.

Comment: So `양놈` is something like `yankee`. (For addition, it sounds alike!)

Answer (score 1):

As is the case with a lot of expressions used between friends and close contacts, the phrase is more of a way of saying "eh, you have time, why not make a friend." In this context, it seems like it's also implying someone more than a friend

Comment: Makes sense! So not necessarily something negative. Thank you!